# Run Google Chrome or Firefox Windowless from the Command Line

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, scripting, command-line, wget

I need to automate a task to pull down a set of web pages and process the HTML. Before someone suggests using wget or curl, I need some JS to execute to change the DOM.

I'd like to script Chrome or Firefox to fetch the HTML and render the JS without actually spawning a visual interface. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

> Selenium Remote Control (RC) is a test tool that allows you to write
>   automated web application UI tests in any programming language against
>   any HTTP website using any mainstream JavaScript-enabled browser.